# UltiSnips#Edit Error when attempting :UltiSnipsEdit

Tags: c++, vim, ultisnips

I have installed UltiSnips through Vundle as per the instructions given on the git page. :PluginInstall did not return any errors, so I assumed it worked well. Upon trying to use :UltiSnipsEdit, though, I received a set of errors:

```
Error detected while processing function UltiSnips#Edit:
line 8:
E121: Undefined variable: file
E116: Invalid arguments for function len(file)
E15: Invalid expression: !len(file)
```

I have tried clarifying the path to my directories through:

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=['/h/usr/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets/UltiSnips/']
```

where here I've used 'usr' to indicate my personal user directory in /h. I similarly clarified my paths to python, as [another post I saw with the exact same error](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/issues/1072) had an issue with that. Neither of these have worked. UltiSnips does not work at all at the moment either, not just this command.

I am quite new to vim customization and vim more generally, and would greatly appreciate any insights into this issue.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker/support channels.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the problem. UltiSnips requires that I have python3 enabled in vim. Running :version shows that I do not have python3 enabled, and thus UltiSnips cannot work on my current vim build.